# Paper towel conjecture

Tags: probability, recreational-mathematics

A group of people share a single roll of paper towels, and when the roll runs out, the person who used the last bit is always the one to replace the roll with a fresh one from the box. The usage patterns vary from person to person; just as an example, one person might use 5 paper towels at once to clean up a big spill, but randomly and infrequently, while another person might use 1/2 of a paper towel every day as a napkin. A third person might gradually increase or decrease their paper towel usage over time. A fourth person might mimic what the third person does, always using the same amount of paper towels as the third person, immediately after the third person does so. These are just examples of the diversity of paper towel strategies. The only assumption on usage patterns is that each person uses paper towels independently of how many are left in the current roll.

Under these conditions, it seems intuitive that the long-run proportion of times a given person replaced the paper towel roll is the same as the long-run proportion of paper towels that person used.

Is this a theorem?

Comment: Not with the conditions you have. For example everyday person A could use a third in the morning, person B uses a third for lunch, and person C uses a third at night. Then only person C ever replaces the roll.

Comment: @OwenSizemore But then their usage patterns would not be independent of how many are left in the roll

Comment: @causative: Yes, they are. The usage pattern is not about how much is left but about the (I guess fixed?!) size of a fresh roll. OK, on further thinking about it: Given the described usage pattern in total, one will have (depending on the exact modeling) a dependence introduced by way of several confounding (or whatever) variables.

Comment: @PhoemueX Well, I guess it is vague what it means for a "usage pattern" to be independent of how many are left in the roll, but you can predict who is using the paper towels given that you know how many are left in the roll. There is a dependence there - the amount left in the roll and the amount used by person A both depend on time, in a way that lets you predict one from the other. If this does not convince you, try altering the problem like so: each roll holds an amount uniformly distributed between C-ε and C+ε towels, for C>0,ε>0, ε<<C.